# How to alert numbers in a for loop

Tags: javascript, function

Please help me fix this code

HTML

```
<p class="imgclass">Test1</p>
<p class="imgclass">Test2</p>
<p class="imgclass">Test3</p>
```

JavaScript

```
imgclassElements = document.getElementsByClassName('imgclass');
for (var i = 0; i < imgclassElements.length; i++){
    imgclassElements[i].onmouseover=function(){alert(i);};
}
```

In browser `onmouseover` elements with class `.imgclass` appear alertbox only with text "3". How fix this? I want to pop-up alert window with values appropriate `.imgclass` elements order.

Comment: Hi Ivan.  You've asked a very, very common JavaScript question, but unless you know the magic phrase 'Closure', it is very difficult to find the answer.

Comment: @J.J.Starcher if he new what the word closure meant he would not be pitching his question: our job is to know he needs a closure, show him one and explain it, not slap him on the head.

Comment: @MartinWebb I don't see any head-slapping here. I think Jeremy did a good job mentioning the word "closure" here and providing the answer by linking to the appropriate question.

Comment: @dirkk: fair enough point made. I think we are all here to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant way, but

```
imgclassElements[i].addEventListener('mouseover',function(j){return function(){alert(j);};}(i));
```

should do it.

That said, you should really read up on JS closures as suggested in the comments to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way to do it, you can use a closure but I'll keep it simple. Also you can access the element and apply styles, or get info from it in the click handler

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/bz7a2vf5/1/

**HTML**

```
<p id="item1" class="imgclass">Test1</p>
<p id="item2" class="imgclass">Test2</p>
<p id="item3" class="imgclass">Test3</p>
```

**JS**

```
imgclassElements = document.getElementsByClassName('imgclass');
for (var i = 0; i < imgclassElements.length; i++) {
    click(i);
}

function click(i){
       imgclassElements[i].onmouseover = function (e) {

       // you can also get the element from e.target
       alert(i);
       alert(e.target.id);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That problem is occurring because of the time `alert` is being called, value of `i` is incremented to `3` that's why it's giving `3` every time.

Try to bind a function with the current value of `i` like bellow

```
imgclassElements = document.getElementsByClassName('imgclass');
  var printVal = function(i){
    return function(){
        alert(i);
    };
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < imgclassElements.length; i++){
    imgclassElements[i].onmouseover = printVal(i)
  }
```

There can be better solutions also.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to extract the content of your loop in a function

```
function handleElement(element, i) {
    element.onmouseover=function(){alert(i);};
};
for (var i = 0; i < imgclassElements.length; i++){
    handleElement(imgclassElements[i], i);
}
```

---

Or you can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach) (Sadly it's a HTMLCollection and not an Array, so it's a bit difficult)

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(imgclassElements, function(element, i) {
    element.onmouseover=function(){alert(i);};
});
```

---

Or give the index as an argument

```
for (var i = 0; i < imgclassElements.length; i++){
    imgclassElements[i].onmouseover=(function(i){alert(i);}).bind(null, i);
}
```

And always a good thing to learn about closures